# ONOS vs Opendaylight what are the factors need to be considered

Tags: opendaylight, onos

What all factors need to be considered when I have to choose between ONOS and Opendaylight ?

> ONOS focuses on performance and scalability ,whereas
>
> ODL focuses on bringing Legacy and NGN together

This is what I found on internet.

All the references and studies are from **2016** or **2017**. Both ODL and ONOS released many versions after that.

- Does OpenDayLight still lack scalability and high availability ? (**Neon** Version)
- Is there any other factors which need to be considered while choosing
  between ONOS and ODL for my usecase ?

Note : My requirement includes a traffic steering in hub and spoke architecture for Service Provider and an SD-WAN MANO.